# Can I disable auto formatting in vs2008?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, view

How can I disable auto formatting for views (html files) in vs2008?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> HTML -> Tabs [Indenting = None]

Comment: Clearly this does not work.
If you turn off everything including the automatic tabs indenting, it will still reformat your html tags.